# Knockout Attr Binding Not Updating

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to teach myself KnockoutJs, and I thought a simple image gallery page would be a good way to increase complexity a little. Unfortunately, I'm already hitting problems that I can't seem to figure out.

My template looks like this:

```
<div>
    <img data-bind="attr: { alt: selectedImage.description, src: selectedImage.sourceUrl }">
</div>
<div data-bind="foreach: images">
    <img data-bind="attr: { alt: description, src: sourceUrl }, event: { click: onClick }">
</div>
```

Which should be simple enough. Then I have my script with some dummy data:

```
(function ($, ko) {
    'use strict';

    function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;

        self.images = [
            new ImageViewModel(self, { description: 'some image alt', sourceUrl: '/someimage.jpg' }),
            new ImageViewModel(self, { description: 'description two', sourceUrl: '/someotherimage.jpg' })
        ];

        self.selectedImage = ko.observable(self.images[0]);

        return self;
    }

    function ImageViewModel(gallery, image) {
        var self = this;

        self.description = ko.observable(image.description);

        self.sourceUrl = ko.observable(image.sourceUrl);

        self.onClick = function (data, event) {
            gallery.selectedImage(data);
        };

        return self;
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
})(jQuery, ko);
```

My problem is that the `selectedImage` binding never works. It doesn't work initially, and it doesn't work when I click one of the thumbnails. It always renders the same:

```
<div>
    <img data-bind="attr: { alt: selectedImage.description, src: selectedImage.sourceUrl }">
</div>
<div data-bind="foreach: images">
    <img src="/someimage.jpg" alt="some image alt" data-bind="attr: { alt: description, src: sourceUrl }, event: { click: onClick }">
    <img src="/someotherimage.jpg" alt="description two" data-bind="attr: { alt: description, src: sourceUrl }, event: { click: onClick }">
</div>
```

I'm sure it's something simple, but I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out what's wrong. There's no error in the console or anything. The `foreach` binding works fine, but the `selectedImage.*` bindings don't.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selectedImage variable is an observable, and observables are functions.
Thus you forgot to use the parenthesis here. ;)

```
<img data-bind="attr: { alt: selectedImage.description, src: selectedImage.sourceUrl }">
```

It should be.

```
<img data-bind="attr: { alt: selectedImage().description, src: selectedImage().sourceUrl }">
```

Or if you want to get rid of the parenthesis use the "with" binding.
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html

Comment: I knew it was something simple. Thank you.

Comment: The `with` binding is nifty. I hadn't gotten past `foreach` in the documentation yet :)

Comment: No problem. It'll come handy the moment where you will not be sure if the observable will have a value or not.